# General purpose ViewModel class

Tags: c#, mvvm, reflection, reference

My objective is to make a ViewModel class that takes any type of object and breaks it out into an ObservableCollection of its fields that can be displayed and modified in a View. I'm imagining the fields being wrapped in a FieldViewModel that exposes a 'string FieldName' property, as well as an 'object Value' property and maybe the Type.

```
class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel(ref object instance)
    {
        foreach (var field in instance.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            Fields.Add(new FieldViewModel(instance, field));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel> _fields = new ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel> Fields
    {
        get { return _fields; }
        set
        {
            _fields = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The above pseudo-code is an attempt to try communicating my intention. Of course more code would be needed to determine if fields are read-only. If this is not possible, how would you recommend doing this? Please advise.

NOTE: my particular application only cares about fields, as opposed to properties. I did not create the data Models that I will be displaying in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way that works for my purposes. This could be extended to work with properties as well, and it still needs proper error handling for user text input.

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel(object instance)
    {
        foreach (var field in instance.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            Fields.Add(new FieldViewModel(instance, field));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel> _fields = new ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel> Fields
    {
        get { return _fields; }
        set
        {
            _fields = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And the FieldViewModel is as follows...

```
public class FieldViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private object _instance;
    private FieldInfo _fieldInfo;
    private Type _fieldType;

    public FieldViewModel(object instance, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    {
        _instance = instance;
        _fieldInfo = fieldInfo;

        _fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType;

        IsReadOnly = fieldInfo.IsInitOnly || fieldInfo.IsLiteral;
        FieldName = fieldInfo.Name;
        TypeName = fieldInfo.FieldType.Name;
    }


    private bool _IsReadOnly;
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return _IsReadOnly; }
        private set
        {
            _IsReadOnly = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private string _fieldName;
    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return _fieldName; }
        set
        {
            _fieldName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _typeName;
    public string TypeName
    {
        get { return _typeName; }
        set
        {
            _typeName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _fieldInfo.GetValue(_instance);
        }
        set
        {
            _fieldInfo.SetValue(_instance, Convert.ChangeType(value, _fieldType));
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage looks like...

```
Person personInstance = new Person
{
    Name = "automagically",
    Age = 25,
    Height = 185.2,
    IsMarried = false
};

ViewModel = new ViewModel(personInstance);
```

And the View...

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Fields}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldName}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding TypeName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Which looks like this...

[image: I can't embed images yet...]

Answer (score 0):

A ObservableCollection of ExpandoObjects might be able to do that. It is basically a Dictionary with some Syntax sugar - and INotifyPropertyChanged notification on every change for every key. The rest would have to be itterating over the fields of the original model via reflection.

Ideally you should not try to sidestep Strong Typisation, however. This class exists primarily to allow interop with weakly typed webserves and the like. Strong Typisaiton is one of your biggest friends. Just look at the PHP and JavaScript examples form this Webcomic to see why: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/

Comment: The Visual Studio IDE has a feature similar to what I want. When you debug and look at an object, you have access to read/write all properties and fields contained in that object. I understand they implement this feature in a completely different fashion, but I feel it is reasonable to want such a View + ViewModel.

Comment: @automagically: as I understand it you want that to happen at runtime. Dynamic compilation on that level is not really supported. It would also cause no end of issues with the Version tracking.

Comment: I got it working, but it still needs to be wrapped in tests and currently doesn't handle invalid user inputs. Take a look at my posted answer and let me know if you think there's anything fundamentally wrong with it. Thanks.